# how to include items in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, drawer

Here is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// inisiasi toolbar
private Toolbar toolbar;

// navigation drawer
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

String title = "My App";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }



    initDrawer();
}

/**
 * init navigation drawer thing
 */
private void initDrawer() {
    //setup navigation drawer
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.txt_open, R.string.txt_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            // when drawer closed
            toolbar.setTitle(title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            // when drawer open
            toolbar.setTitle("Nav menu");
        }
    };

    // setDrawerlisterner
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

and here is xml file layout view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- Toolbar -->

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<!-- content -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Our Content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- nav drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Nav drawer"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to add a listview to navigation drawer. And i want to load a web page when user selects each item on navigation drawer into a fragment. I tried to implement a code from a sample but comes up with so many errors.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: add listview to your linearlayout. then define that listview in activity class. use adapter. set onItemClickListener to the listview. if u want more detail, plz post ur exact requirement with main activity class

Comment: I have posted my MainActivity class file. Tell me how to view a webpage onclick to each listview item..

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is nothing to afraid about NavigationDrawer. At first we may think that it is some special kind of activity and this and that. but it is so much simple.

**Step 1** - Create xml file with 2 layouts

```
<FrameLayout>

     //main screen contents

</FrameLayout>

<Linear/Relative/ListView/xyz>

      // any layout that u want to be shown in navigation drawer

</Linear/Relative/ListView/xyz>
```

**Step 2** - Define ur drawer in activity class with couple of codes

```
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.NvDrawer);
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
```

and override this methods

```
    @Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float v) {

}


@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {

}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

}

@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int i) {

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

**Step 3** - Add this code in onOptionsItemSelected

```
if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
```

Comment: Ok.. then u haven't mentioned anything about onclick each listview item show a webpage..

Comment: that too as usual. listview.setOnItemClickListener and do whatever u want to do with the clicks.

Comment: are u getting an error or something? plz post that code. bcoz it has worked in my case